# Div center issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, center

I have main container 940 pixel

with 2 divs inside main container of width 250px each

I want these boxes to be centered align with main container. however issue is that the second div dynamically adds. So in case the second div is not there the first one should center. and when the second div is added then both should be cenetered as per 940 px main div.

I tried a lot but could not get to the solution. please help!

Here is the simplified code

**CSS**

```
   div.box {
    background: #EEE;
    height: 400px;
    width: 940px;
}
div.left {
    background: #999;
    float: left;
    height: 390px;
    width: 250px;
}
div.right {
    background: #666;
    height: 390px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="box">

       <div class="left">Tree</div>
       <div class="right">View</div> ( this div will dynamically add)
       <div class="clear" />

    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: where is your source code? here image not display

Comment: I am not able to post images yet so I have edited my comments. Added the code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

make this `remove` `clear:both;` class

http://jsfiddle.net/jWVxd/4/

CSS

```
  div.box {
    width: 940px;
    background: #EEE;
    height: 400px;
    display: table;
    padding:10px;
}
div.left {
    background: #999;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
}
div.right {
    background: #666;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: OP wants div to be in center, have checkd your Jsfiddle its not solved

Answer (score 0):

Try out this in your `div.box` css

```
 margin:0px auto;
```

For demo chk this out [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9afaF/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin:auto;` to your `div.box` and it will come in center

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqt5b/5/)**

**Edited:**
Here have hide the 2nd div (".right") and its working fine

**[2nd Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqt5b/6/)** now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) see its in center

Comment: Thanks for replying. but when you try and remove the second box. the first box do not center in your example.